# How to find another directory without explicitly stating it? (Python)

Tags: python, image, copy, directory

I am trying to copy all the contents of a folder from one directory to another, but the final destination path is outside of the current working directory that Python is searching though.

How do I find this location without explicitly stating it?

Here's what I have:

```
from Myro import *
import shutil
import os
import sys

def imageSync():
    path1 = os.path.abspath("5-1-15 upload")
    path2 = "C:\Users\Owner\Pictures\plsWork" 
    #path2 = sys.path.inset(0, 'C:\Users\Owner\Pictures\plsWork')

    listing = os.listdir(path1)

    for image in listing:
        shutil.copy2( os.path.join(path1, image), path2)
```

I guess my problem is similar to: [Importing files from different folder in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4383571/importing-files-from-different-folder-in-python). But I tried those suggestions and received a Type Error, so I commented out my attempts that didn't work.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your problem. Is path1 or path2 the final destination path? Something makes me think your problem is the `\U` not being escaped into `\\U`.

Comment: @EugeneK path2 is my destination path

Comment: Try escaping every \ in your strings. \ is used as a path separator on Windows and is also the escape character in Python. Reference: http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/ex10.html

Comment: what version of python?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham 3.1

Comment: Ok then you have a serious problem with the U, use `r"C:\Users\Owner\Pictures\plsWork" `

Comment: @EugeneK So should I use \\ instead of \? But I would still be stating the location

Comment: @AlinaDW Yes you have to do \\ to escape a \ so that it isn't interpreted as a special character. Or you can do what Padraic suggested which essentially disables escaping in the string. What is wrong with stating the location? The only problem should be that it's user specific. But it should execute on your machine.

Comment: @EugeneK I was hoping to be able to move images from various folders from one network to another, unless that's not possible? I was just trying to start a basic code to move some stuff within a local directory on my own computer just to get familiar with moving stuff

Comment: @AlinaDW haven't worked with networked drives in a bit, but I know Python has some issues. This might help out: http://developer.covenanteyes.com/unc-paths-with-python/

Comment: @EugeneK Perfect, that link seems to summarize what I'm trying to do. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

The `\U` will casue an error:

```
In [2]: "\U"
  File "<ipython-input-2-d8a2543b5007>", line 1
    "\U"
        ^
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 0-1: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape
```

You should always use raw string `r` or forward `/'s` in your windows paths.

```
r"C:\Users\Owner\Pictures\plsWork"
```

Or `/`:

```
"C:/Users/Owner/Pictures/plsWork"
```

[string literals](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals)

> The backslash () character is used to escape characters that otherwise have a special meaning, such as newline, backslash itself, or the quote character. String literals may optionally be prefixed with a letter 'r' or 'R'; such strings are called raw strings and use different rules for interpreting backslash escape sequences. A prefix of 'u' or 'U' makes the string a Unicode string